# Chow form of closure of product of affine varieties given the chow forms of their closurs

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-varieties

This question is about the connection between $\overline{X\times Y}$ and $\overline{X}$,$\overline{Y}$ where $X\subset \mathbb{A}^{n},\;Y\subset\mathbb{A}^{m}$ are affine varities over an algebraically closed field $k$, where the closure is in corresponding projective space. More specifically, given the chow forms $f,g$ of $\overline{X}$,$\overline{Y}$, what is the chow form of $\overline{X\times Y}$?

Here is one possible way to procceed - from $f,g$ one can extract equations for $X$,$Y$, then form equations for $X\times Y$, take the closure and take chow form. This is computable, and probably even good enough for my purpose.

However, I am looking for any geometric insight into this problem, how can one even find $\overline{X\times Y}$ using $\overline{X},\overline{Y}$ using normal operations in projective space, i.e joins, intersection with divisors, segre embedding etc.

Any references or ideas will be appreciated.